# git pull from remote but no such ref was fetched?

Tags: git

I have a git mirror on my disk and when I want to update my repo with git pull it gives me error message:

```
 Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref '3.5/master' from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

It also gives me:

```
  1ce6dac..a5ab7de  3.4/bfq    -> origin/3.4/bfq
  fa52ab1..f5d387e  3.4/master -> origin/3.4/master
  398cc33..1c3000a  3.4/upstream-updates -> origin/3.4/upstream-updates
  d01630e..6b612f7  3.7/master -> origin/3.7/master
  491e78a..f49f47f  3.7/misc   -> origin/3.7/misc
  5b7be63..356d8c6  3.7/upstream-updates -> origin/3.7/upstream-updates
  636753a..027c1f3  3.8/master -> origin/3.8/master
  b8e524c..cfcf7b5  3.8/misc   -> origin/3.8/misc
  * [neuer Zweig]     3.8/upstream-updates -> origin/3.8/upstream-updates
```

When I run make menuconfig it gives me Linux version 3.5.7? What does this mean? How can I update my repo?

Comment: The remote branch might be removed by someone.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/36984371/12534

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Check the branch you are on (`git branch`), check the configuration for that branch (in `.../.git/config`), you probably are on the wrong branch or your configuration for it tells to merge with a (now?) non-existent remote branch.

Comment: To remove non-existent remote branch references in your local repository, use `git remote prune origin`.

Comment: Another way to "check the configuration" for a branch is: `git branch -vv`.  That displays the branch's associated "remote".

Comment: renamed the branch? 
don't forget to update the remote branch reference in `.git/confg`

Answer (score 38):

In my case, my local branch was not set to track the remote branch. I had to manually run:

```
git pull origin remotebranch
```

Then next time you do a push do "git push -u" to set up correct tracking.

Comment: The same goes for when you first clone an empty repo ie created using `git init --bare`

Answer (score 15):

In my case, my local branch and remote branch had different capitalization.

To resolve this I deleted my local branch `$ git branch -d branch-name`, then checked out the remote branch again using `$ git fetch` and `$ git checkout Branch-name`.

Comment: Its clean, simple and working fine. Thank you.

Comment: I got this error in cmd line.  Tried SmartGit with a rebase and got past it.

Comment: Do this once instead of delete branch and re-checkout branch every single time:
Correct capitalization in your /.git/config

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to call the following commands manually:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

(c) https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800341/741782

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that someone else on your team simply merged your branch and deleted it (commonly done after merging).  You can make the branch on the repo and try again.  It's happens to me at my company every once in a while (bitbucket defaults to merge and delete).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when running out of disk space. After resizing the volume, the error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

If the branch is gone,

```
$ git status
On branch blah_gone_now
Your branch is based on 'origin/1234/blah_gone_now', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

$ git branch --unset-upstream
```

Then checkout master or whatever you need

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was also capitalization of the remote's name, but lower case on the local working copy. I fixed this by reestablishing the upstream:

```bsh
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/UPPER-case-branch
```

This gave me a successful message:

```bsh
Branch 'upper-case-branch' set up to track remote branch 'UPPER-case-branch' from 'origin'.
```

Afterwards, the `git pull` worked normally.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (the usual caveat), I already had a branch of the appropriate name so I only had to add `remote = origin` to my .git/config:

```
[branch "sparql"]
    merge = refs/heads/sparql
    remote = origin # <-- added
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue due to a casing problem that manifests itself on Windows.

My Git config looked like:

```
[branch "Bug/some_branch"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/Bug/some_branch
```

On the server, both "Bug" and "bug" existed as part of multiple branches. Windows can only hold one of these at a time though, due to the file system mapping. Therefore, I manually updated my config to match the server version, which actually solved the pull issue:

```
[branch "Bug/some_branch"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/bug/some_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

This may occur if someone has renamed the remote branch.

If you need to resolve it without manually determine the new branch to pull from, try this:

```
default_branch=$(git remote show origin | awk '/HEAD branch/ { print $3 }')
git branch -m $default_branch
git branch -u origin/$default_branch
git pull
```

This will get the head branch name from origin, rename the current local branch, set it to track from the remote branch, and then pull.

Answer (score 0):

This  one is old but if someone lands into this page,

the solution that worked for us was to check the casing, git is case sensitive.

check .git/config file to match your repository branch name.

Comment: Welcome to U&L, your answer is same as @Feckmore's